# How to access one class variable in another class using Java?

Tags: java, string

I have created 2 classes as follows...

```
public class A extends JFrame {
    public String x = "abcdefg";
}

public class B extends JFrame {
    public String y;
}
```

Both of these classes extend `JFrame`. I am wondering whether there is a way that the `String y` in `Class B` can inherit the value of `String x` in `Class A`? I want it such that updating either `x` or `y` will also update the other String.

Is there a way that I can make these Strings common to the 2 classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make class B extend A.

```
public class A extends JFrame {

}

public class B extends A {

}
```

But TBH, we all think it's a terrible idea to have public fields!

Comment: Then instead of public make it protected.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this..

```
class a
{
    private String aVal = "abc";

    public String returnAVal(){
         return aVal;
    }
}

class b extends a
{
    private String y = returnAVal();

    public void testY(){
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

PhilNerd

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to have Inheritance for the sake of single varibale.check [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Make it private and provide setters and getters to access it.